# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#

My code:

```
public void FillMaxBankCode()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = bol.SelectMaxBankCode();
        string j = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
        txtbankid.Text = int.Parse(j); //ERROR HERE
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}



  public DataSet SelectMaxBankCode()
    {
        try
        {
            **Squery = "EXEC SelectMaxBankCode";**
            return dal.DBread(Squery);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am new to C# and the above code show error.. can anyone help?

Comment: not a c# expert, but it seems to me you are converting a string to int, when in fact you need a string value in the first place?

Comment: i want to show bank id in the text box..what can i do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`txtbankid.Text` property type is a string. Don't use `int.parse`.  There is no need to.  Just do: `txtbankid.Text = j;`

Comment: Better than that.. no need for additional variable, just have `txtbankid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();`

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString(); 
Is not very nice anyway. You should check for NULLs and remove the try catch

Comment: if iam putting like this txtbankid.Text = j; im not getting number,it shows system.draw......

Comment: @Guru, check and see what j is. based on what you say it is quite possible that your are puling the wrong information from the data table and that is causing the issue.

Comment: im fetch the bankid from the database..but in the form it displays the string.. so that only i convert int.parse.

Comment: public DataSet SelectMaxBankCode()
        {
            try
            {
                Squery = "EXEC SelectMaxBankCode";
                return dal.DBread(Squery);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

Comment: @Guru: Post the entire error message after removing int.parse

Comment: Result Is :  public void FillMaxBankCode()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = bol.SelectMaxBankCode();
                txtbankid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FillMaxBankCode()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = bol.SelectMaxBankCode();
                string j = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
                txtbankid.Text = j;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if iam putting like this txtbankid.Text = j; im not getting number,it shows system.draw.....

Comment: @Gugu: Post all code and error messages that are relevant to this discussion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`int.Parse(..)` is for converting a string containing digits into an integer. You are trying to perform the function `int.Parse(..)` on a string but then assign it to another string. That won't work because `int.Parse(..)` returns and integer. Read here about [Int32.Parse (String) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the value is an integer before assigning it I suggest you use TryParse

```
// check if the table and row exists
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string j = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(j, out value))
        txtbankid.Text = value.ToString();
}
```